# Not able to override default values of use.schema.id, auto.register.schemas in mqtt source connector kafka-connect confluent using JsonSchemaConverter

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-schema-registry

```
schema.registry.url = \[http://13.127.201.183:30068\] 
use.latest.version = false 
use.schema.id = -1
```

What is the use of use.schema.id?

Connector Configuration for Kafka-connect:

```
{
  "name": "TEST12",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.mqtt.MqttSourceConnector",
    "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://13.127.201.183:30068",

"confluent.topic.bootstrap.servers": "aepv6-base-shell-kafka:9092",

    "auto.register.schemas": "false",
    "tasks.max": "2",
    "name": "TEST12",
    "kafka.topic": "TEST-KAFKA-12",
    "mqtt.topics": "TEST-MQTT",
    "mqtt.server.uri": "tcp://broker.hivemq.com:1883",
    "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.json.JsonSchemaConverter",
    "confluent.license.topic.replication.factor": "1",

    "use.schema.id": "1"
  },
```

I tried use.schema.id=1, where 1 is the global schema id where schema is present.

http://13.127.201.183:30068/schemas/ids/1 :

```
"schema": "{"type":"record","name":"test","fields":

\[{"name":"field1","type":"string"},{"name":"field2","type":"int"}\]}"
```

I expected the topic to only allow data in adherence to this format, but it is allowing everything that comes from MQTT source to kafka

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to prefix those properties with `value.converter.`  to actually set them for the Converter, like you did for the registry address, rather than trying to apply them to the the MQTT connector config.

> What is the use of

[Source code can answer that](https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/blob/master/schema-serializer/src/main/java/io/confluent/kafka/serializers/AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDeConfig.java#L77)

> allowing everything that comes from MQTT source to kafka

I don't think the connector will validate record content. It'll simply serialize whatever it gets.

Comment: Thank you, for the answer. It helped me a lot.

Wanted to ask, about the serialization. I am getting the error while producing messages on kafka : 

Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Failed to serialize Avro data from topic TEST-KAFKA-four :

Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error serializing Avro message

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Incompatible schema Set id.compatibility.strict=false to disable this check

Comment: How to override value.serializer in kafka-connect connector config?

Default serializer is org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer.

and, I want to serialize avro messages using io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer.

Please let me know if I am missing something?

Comment: You want Avro but you set JSONSchema in the question? That's what `value.converter` does, but read the documentation of the MQTT connector more closely and you'll see it's only capable of sending strings or bytes. For any other error, please create a new post